# Dump of SQL database of instance via Cloud SQL Admin API v1beta4

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've created Cloud Function written in node.js to make dump of database in SQL instance and I'm wondering,  is there  any recommendation about stopping all instance before making dump? I stopped instance, but after that i couldn't make "dump".

There is a documentation: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/instances/export

Comment: Stopping an instance means shutting down the VM instance, you cannot dump a database after you stop it. What do you mean by stopping all instance before making dump ?

Comment: So, is there any recommendation? I'm worried about a situation where someone will add a new data into the datebase while  the dump is creating.

Comment: Unless you have a way to stop all your apps from writing data while you taking dump. The recommendation is to take dumps often.

Comment: why do you want to make a dump offline?